# No internet connection during doze mode

Tags: android, networking, internet-connection, doze

In my application I need to download data from a website every 15 minutes. My problem is that when the phone is in doze mode the connection is absent due to energy savings.I tried with a WakefulBroadcastReceiver that is activated every 15 minutes by an Alam manager but the connection is almost always absent because the phone remains in doze mode. I have read of jobscheduler but not if it is useful to my problem and possibly how to implement it.Does anyone have an example of code that allows me to download data from a site by waking the phone from the doze mode every 15 minutes?

Comment: I don't know any of the details of your app. But I think you are right to consider using JobScheduler, Also it has enough smarts in it to detect if the network is available before scheduling the job: "setRequiredNetwork: Calling this method defines network as a strict requirement for your job". But there are no guarantees as to how often it will run during doze.

Comment: In detail in my app I download an image from a website every 15 minutes. Through a "checkImage" method I compare the downloaded image with the previously archived one. If the phone is connected to the wi-fi network, the download is successful at the set intervals but if the phone is connected to the telephone network I have no connection because of the doze. In fact, I often receive the absent network error or timeout. Could you give me an example of jobscheduler code or what you think is suitable to solve the problem?

Comment: I implemented a JobScheduler last week based on this tutorial. [Job Scheduler Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html). Every 15 minutes is a reasonable, but arbitrary goal. Modern Android devices with aggressive power saving do not want to be told when to run. JobScheduler is pretty blunt about it: "You have no control over when within this interval this job will be executed, only the guarantee that it will be executed at most once within this interval"

Comment: It sounds like JobScheduler is the right option for this app. But if you do ultimately decide to carry on with the AlarmManager implementation, I suspect the service will be more likely to gain a full internet connection if it is started in the foreground if for no other reason than the service will be able to run for a longer period. But again, JobScheduler is best if you can tolerate potential delays.

Answer (score 0):

Elletlar, I followed the example you indicated for the implementation of a jobScheduler in my project with excellent results. Now I wanted to ask you if in the "onJobStart" method you can indicate more 'intent as I did in the attached code. Thanks.

```
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    //first Job
    Intent service1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Service1.class);
    getApplicationContext().startService(service1);
    Util.scheduleJob(getApplicationContext()); // first job!
    //second job
    Intent service2=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Service2.class);
    getApplicationContext().startService(service2);
    Util.scheduleJob(getApplicationContext()); // second job!
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Couple things to be aware of, firstly this will not work if the app targetSdkVersion is set to 27+ because the framework has changed to require startServiceInForeground to be called instead [though ContextCompat.startServiceInForeground is probably the best]

Comment: Secondly, I'm not sure I would start 2 JobServices from one on onStartJob. Is that necessary? I see people sometimes creating 2 services when they only need an additional 'Manager' class or maybe another thread in the existing service. But, jobFinished() must be called: "Call this to inform the JobScheduler that the job has finished its work. When the system receives this message, it releases the wakelock being held for the job." I think it will be simpler to finish the job if there is only 1 service OR 1 service per job.

Comment: Lastly, just be aware of the meaning of the return value in inStartJob: If you "return true from this method if your job needs to continue running. If you do this, the job remains active until you call jobFinished(JobParameters, boolean) to tell the system that it has completed its work..."

Comment: By 'active', it means it holds a partial wakelock.